# Data is not fetching after a reload (React js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is the useEffect I am using now. I get the data from api and put them to setData. If I don't give a reload and save the code then the data is available but when I use "data" in the return part it shows me error, basically the data is empty when I reload the page.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(http://192.168.68.105:8084/api/courses)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.data.courseData));
  }, []);
```

I have used the same process on another component but that is working fine, I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function"  "data={}"
```

ERROR: the page is getting blank. even when I console log the data it gets empty. but all these happens when I reload the page

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function"

the page is getting blank. even when I console log the data it gets empty. but all these happens when I reload the page

Comment: Well, it sounds like the result of your request (`data.data.courseData`) is an object rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you. My default state was the culprit for the error. I declared it an object rather than an array